# How to get a Read-Write Reference to Parent GameObject from a script component attached to it?

Tags: unity

I have a game object(object) with a script component(myscript) attached.

I have a reference to myscript component through getComponent, and I want to change the transform of the gameObject the script is attached to.

```
myscript.gameObject.transform = (new value);
```

The above code gives me error,

> Property 'UnityEngine.GameObject.transform' is read only.

Is there a way to get a read-write version?

Comment: hmm.. it seems that I can just use myscript.transform
but it also gives the same read-only error.

Comment: What value do you want to change? Position? Try assigning to `transform.position`. Local rotation? Try assigning to `transform.localRotation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform is **read-only** C# property. I guess it could be defined pretty most this way:

```
public Transform transform{get;}
```

So, you can't assign directly a `Transform` to another `Transform` (you don't have set accessor defined).
You are forced to assign individual fields of each `Transform` to the other.

For example:

```
myscript.gameObject.transform.rotation = otherScript.gameObject.transform.rotation;
myscript.gameObject.transform.position = otherScript.gameObject.transform.position;
...
```

Comment: FIY, it doesn't have a setter defined at all, and getter reads the value from native code.

Answer (score 1):

If by "change the transform" you mean "change position/rotation/scale" of my object, you have to change these individually:

```
gameObject.transform.position = ...;
gameObject.transform.rotation = ...;
gameObject.transform.localScale = ...; // note that you CAN'T change global scale, as it's not actually a vector
```

If by "change the transform" you mean "change my object's parent", you have to change `parent` propery:

```
gameObject.transform.parent = someOtherTransform;
```